# number of repeats does not affect design

Tags: r, statistics, experimental-design

I want to perform an experiment and for this I wanna' create an experiment design via [optfederov](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AlgDesign/versions/1.2.1/topics/optFederov):

```
levels.design = c(3,8)
f.design <- gen.factorial(levels.design, varNames = c("rH", "T"))

optFederov(
            #frml = ~. + quad(T) + rH
            data = f.design
            , approximate = FALSE
            , nRepeats=2
            )
```

Whether I'm using `nRepeats=2` or `nRepeats=10` it doesn't effect the outcome:

```
$D
[1] 3.332222

$A
[1] 0.6756757

$Ge
[1] 0.902

$Dea
[1] 0.898

$design
   rH  T
1  -1 -7
3   1 -7
4  -1 -5
6   1 -5
19 -1  5
21  1  5
22 -1  7
24  1  7

$rows
[1]  1  3  4  6 19 21 22 24
```

and

```
$D
[1] 3.332222

$A
[1] 0.6756757

$Ge
[1] 0.902

$Dea
[1] 0.898

$design
   rH  T
1  -1 -7
3   1 -7
4  -1 -5
6   1 -5
19 -1  5
21  1  5
22 -1  7
24  1  7

$rows
[1]  1  3  4  6 19 21 22 24
```

Comment: This is a naive suggestion but have you tried adding the parameter `nullify=2`? I am suggesting this as we can read in the documentation that `nRepeats` has no effect when `nullify` = 1.

Comment: Tbh, I didn't consider this parameter as I'm not understanding it. But I tried it with $ nullify = {0, 1, 2} $ and it makes differences in the design but the design is still not repeated. Btw, I think it should be called replicated, or not (r documentation says "Number of times the entire process is repeated. ")?

Comment: What makes me also wonder is that there is no randomization and that there is no possibility to opt for?